# Regular expression - SQL manipulation

Tags: linux, text-processing, regular-expression, sql

```
[pol@fedora data]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 34 (Thirty Four)
Release:    34
Codename:   ThirtyFour
```

I'm trying to convert a sample database file from MS SQL Server to PostgreSQL.

So, I'm having two small niggles that I can't resolve.

```
shipname       NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
```

That's

- (**always**) two spaces
- identifier (i.e. field name) - always [a-z] - lower case alphabetical
- followed by an unknown number of spaces
- followed by NVARCHAR(xy) NOT NULL **or** it may be followed by NVARCHAR(xy) NULL

and I want to transform this into

```
shipname       TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH(shipname)  <= xy),
```

or

```
shipname       TEXT NULL,
```

What I have so far:

```
sed 's/^  [a-z]+[ ]+NVARCHAR([0-9]+) NOT NULL/TEXT NOT NULL CHECK \(LENGTH\((\1) <= (\2)\)/g'
```

So,

- `^` is the beginning of the string
- followed by two spaces
- followed by my field name [a-z]+
- followed by an arbitrary no. of spaces [ ]+
- NVARCHAR([0-9]+)

and substitute in

`TEXT` followed by NOT NULL then CHECK(LENGTH(xy) - back reference 1 - <= back reference 2...

I've tried various permutations and combinations of the above, but nothing appears to work for me.

```
[pol@fedora data]$ sed 's/^  [a-z]+[ ]+NVARCHAR([0-9]+) NOT NULL/TEXT NOT NULL CHECK \(LENGTH\((\1) <= (\2)\)/g' 
sed: -e expression #1, char 87: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

Get invalid back reference...

**Ideally**, and I stress **ideally**, if the string following NVARCHAR(xy) is `NULL` and **not** `NOT NULL`, I don't want any length check - because it doesn't make sense to take the LENGTH of a NULL... this is conditional behaviour - not sure if it's possible in regexps....

p.s. thought this would be trivial.

Have data like this:

```
N'Strada Provinciale 1234', N'Reggio Emilia', NULL, N'10289', N'Italy');
```

I want to change the `N'` into just plain apostrophe `'` (the `N'` is a SQL Server thing) but I don't want to change the `NULL` into the empty string, or worse `ULL` - so I tried:

```
[pol@fedora data]$ sed 's/N\'\'/g TSQLV5.sql
```

but get

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

I know that I've used `sed` a lot, but would be open to any `awk` commands that could perform the tasks required.

Comment: Does your first instance of `xy` match the `40` from the corresponding original?

Comment: @roaima - not necessarily - xy could be any integer from 5 - 5000 (arbitrary)... hence [0-9]+ - there has to be at least one digit present, so not [0-9]*. That is:  (xy) corresponds to whatever integers would be in those brackets! fieldname VARCHAR(543) => xy = 543 and is the back-reference in the regex! I hope this is clear?

Comment: Yes... I appreciate the generalisation, thanks; I'm trying to check I understand your mapping in the case of the example

Comment: 1. You say "it doesn't make sense to take the LENGTH of a NULL".  Both `region` and `postalcode` are VARCHAR(n) NULL, yet you want them to have a length check in the desired output.   Which is correct?  2. Where does the `test_field` come from?  and the extra blank lines (before birthdate, address, phone)?

Comment: I have rolled back your edit as it substantially changed the question and since you have already received an answer to your original question.  If you have another related issue, then please open a new question rather than re-writing your original question.

Comment: @Kusalananda - OK - my bad... I should have put the full table in first... will ask new question! I've answered a number of questions on another forum and I know that there is nothing more irritating than having the OP "change the goalposts", however I would have thought that it was blindingly obvious that this would apply to multiple lines... a reminder that not everybody is [interested in | consumed by] databases... :-)

Comment: @Vérace You can certainly clarify the current question, but the edit seemed to change what it was you asked for.

Comment: @Kusalananda - no, you are correct - my edit didn't change what I wanted, but it did expand the scope significantly - so, I'll ask another question tomorrow - and by **clear** this time! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got answers, but I want to add what went wrong in your own approach, so you can learn from it instead of just copying some solution:

- You use extended regular expressions, but forgot to give the `-E` option to `sed`.
- You want to reuse the identifier, but you did not enclose it in `()`
- You seem to mix ERE `()` groups with literal ones. You probably mean `sed -E 's/^  ([a-z]+)[ ]+NVARCHAR\(([0-9]+)\) NOT NULL/TEXT NOT NULL CHECK \(LENGTH\((\1) <= (\2)\)/g'`
- The first part up to the spaces doesn't show in the replacement. You also need to group it and use it as reference in the replacement: `sed -E 's/^(  ([a-z]+)[ ]+)NVARCHAR\(([0-9]+)\) NOT NULL/\1TEXT NOT NULL CHECK \(LENGTH\((\2) <= (\3)\)/g'`
- `[ ]+` is the same as  `+`. Not an error, but makes it more confusing to read.
- The `g` option is superfluous. With an anchor like `^` or `$` in the pattern multiple replacements are not possible.
- You can avoid multiple expressions by making the `NOT` optional: `sed -E 's/^(  ([a-z]+) +)NVARCHAR(([0-9]+)) (NOT )?NULL/\1TEXT \4NULL CHECK (LENGTH((\2) <= (\3))/'
- On the other hand, if you want to leave out the check, you can do that with a separate replacement: `s/^(  [a-z]+ +)NVARCHAR\(([0-9]+)\) NULL/\1TEXT NULL/`
- Your `s/N\'\'/g` misses the separator between search pattern and replacement: `s/N\'/\'/g`

So you end up with

```
sed -E 's/^(  ([a-z]+) +)NVARCHAR\(([0-9]+)\) NOT NULL/\1TEXT NOT NULL CHECK \(LENGTH\((\2) <= (\3)\)/
  s/^(  [a-z]+ +)NVARCHAR\(([0-9]+)\) NULL/\1TEXT NULL/
  s/N\'/\'/g'
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you use `fedora` you have `GNU sed` and this should work:

```
s="  shipname       NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,"
echo "$s" | sed -E '/NOT/{s/^  ([[:lower:]]+)\s*NVARCHAR\(([[:digit:]]+)\) NOT NULL,$/\1 TEXT NOT NULL CHECK \(LENGTH\(\1\) <= \2\),/;q0} ; s/^  ([[:lower:]]+)/\1 TEXT NULL,/'
```

This emulates a fake if.

`if`:

a `NOT` (`/NOT/`) is found inside the db structure then the first sed command is executed then, quit (`q0`) without executing the second statement.

`else`:

no `NOT` keyword is found, and the second instance is executed.

---

For the second reqirements :

```
sed "s/N'/'/g"
```

Globally search for `N'` and replace it with only `'`. I found useful to swap `'` with `"` for `sed` command line delimiter and make it more clean without a lot of escaping.

---

Put the first `sed` inside a file:

```
#!/bin/sed -Ef

# If a NOT is found execute this:
# capture the column name and the value of this
/NOT/ {
    s/^  ([[:lower:]]+)\s*NVARCHAR\(([[:digit:]]+)\) NOT NULL,$/\1 TEXT NOT NULL CHECK \(LENGTH\(\1\) <= \2\),/

    # Quit without execute the other statement
    q0
}

# Else: If we are here then the database
# structure does not contains a length for the column;
# so it should be NULL
s/^  ([[:lower:]]+)/\1 TEXT NULL,/
```

The `{` command is used to group more `sed` command togheter.

The `q` is the `quit` command, it is used to make `sed` quit. Here i have use it to force `sed` exiting before encounter the last line if the first test succeded.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is great for some tasks, but some other tasks required a full-featured language, like `awk` or `perl`, with conditionals and printf and more.   And preferably a language that doesn't read like some hideous hybrid of a regex and an RPN calculator :-).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

while(<>) {
  # print verbatim any lines that don't define an identifier
  unless (m/^\s+\S/) { print; next };
  # print a blank line before certain identifiers
  print "\n" if m/birthdate|address|phone/;

  # various regex transformations for IDENTITY and VARCHAR fields
  s/\s+NOT NULL IDENTITY/ GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY/;
  s/([[:lower:]]+)\s+NVARCHAR\((\d+)\) NOT NULL/$1 TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH($1) <= $2)/;
  s/\s+NVARCHAR\((\d+)\)\s+NULL/ TEXT NULL/;

  # remove length checks from NULL definitions
  s/\s+CHECK.*/,/ if /(?<!NOT) NULL/;

  # add a comma at the end of the mgrid line if it's not there
  s/\s*$/,/ if /mgrid/ && ! /,\s*$/;

  # hacky crap to nicely format "TYPE (NOT )?NULL" output.
  my @F = split;
  my $identifier = shift @F;
  my $type = shift @F;
  $type .= " " . shift @F if ($F[0] =~ /NOT/);
  $type = sprintf "%-8s", $type;
  $type .= " " . shift @F if ($F[0] =~ /NULL/);

  printf "  %-15s %-13s%s\n", $identifier, $type, join(" ",'',@F);

  # print the test_field definition after mgrid
  if ($identifier eq 'mgrid') {
    print "  test_field      TEXT     NULL CHECK (LENGTH(test_field) <= 25)\n";
  };
}
```

- this is a fairly brute-force method of transforming your input to (roughly) your desired output.  a few regex transformations, and some code to line up the "fields" nicely.  and a few extra print statements to add blank lines and the test_field in the appropriate places.  As such, it's not generically useful but can be adapted to suit other SQL transformations as required.
- the script implements the description in your question, not what is displayed in the "desired output" (so, for example, both `region` and `postalcode` do not have length checks because they are NULL fields).

Output:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee
(
  empid           INT           GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  lastname        TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH(lastname) <= 20),
  firstname       TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH(firstname) <= 10),
  title           TEXT     NULL,
  titleofcourtesy TEXT     NULL,

  birthdate       DATE NOT NULL,
  hiredate        DATE NOT NULL,

  address         TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH(address) <= 60),
  city            TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH(city) <= 15),
  region          TEXT     NULL,
  postalcode      TEXT     NULL,
  country         TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH(country) <= 15),

  phone           TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH(phone) <= 24),
  mgrid           INT      NULL,
  test_field      TEXT     NULL CHECK (LENGTH(test_field) <= 25)

);
```

Here's a diff of the script's output vs your desired output (after cleaning up to remove comments and some extraneous space characters):

```
-  region          TEXT     NULL CHECK (LENGTH(region) <= 15),
-  postalcode      TEXT     NULL CHECK (LENGTH(postalcode) <= 10),
+  region          TEXT     NULL,
+  postalcode      TEXT     NULL,
```

---

###### Other comments:

- You probably want `PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` for `empid`
- postgresql has a VARCHAR(n) data type, which is probably more appropriate than TEXT,
  and much simpler to transform: `s/NVARCHAR/VARCHAR/`.   VARCHARs have a fixed length,
  so a) don't need the length constraint checks, and b) are faster to index and search.
- Allowing a field to be NULL is the default, so there's no real need to explicitly define them as such.

Comment: Yes, I would want a PK for my table. VARCHARs do **not** have a fixed length  - that's the reason for the name :-) And yes, my regex powers would extend to `'s/NVARCHAR/VARCHAR/g'`! CHAR(n) has a fixed length - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/470530)- also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16525140/470530).

Comment: yes, sorry, sloppy thinking when i wrote that.  I meant CHAR.   Also looks like a lot has changed with TEXT vs CHAR/VARCHAR since I first started using pg (late 90s).  back then, CHAR / VARCHAR were preferable to TEXT.

Comment: Been a long day? Mine's just starting here in Europe :-) (+1 BTW).

Comment: not exactly, but a long night last night and poor sleep.     btw, unless you're doing more constraint checks than just a length check it doesn't seem as if there's any real advantage to using TEXT (and the disadvantage of having to explicitly write the length constraint).

Comment: I'm not sure now.  I'll have to look into it next time it actually matters to me :-).  I've always used VARCHAR(n) for shortish columns up to 256 chars or so (CHAR was always kind of pointless with Pg.  and with bonus annoying padded spaces), and TEXT for bulk text.

Comment: To me, it seems like a good example how to replace some simple and comrehensive `sed` script by a complex and clumsy programming work. (-; My subjective view, maybe influenced by what you are used to.

Comment: @Philippos well, no.   there's more to text processing than just regular expressions.   perl is basically sed + awk + lots of other stuff.  You can write trivial sed-like scripts in perl, and you can write awk-like programs in to too....but you can do so much more that both sed and awk just aren't capable of.    And sure, you can do some basic conditionals in sed (and even a hold buffer! wow!) IF you don't mind the fact that you're programming a modern computer as if it was some 1970s calculator.

Comment: @cas Missed my (-; ? Of course I know that there are task our there that require programming. I just tried to question whether this task is already one of those. Btw, in cases where my handy 70s tool doesn't fit, I don't jump to some 80s stuff, but prefer `python`.

Comment: Python, the language where version management is too hard to even imagine, let alone implement - by and for programmers who think that running system services out of their home directory is a great idea, and taught the world how to abuse `env` to enable it. A language where indentation is syntactically significant, as if that was THE feature to borrow from fortran.  I've done a moderate amount of python programming over the years and the only really good things about it are a) numpy and scipy, and b) it might serve as a good intro to `nim`.   Also, python's no good for text processing  :)

Comment: No good? `import re`